# objdump mips u-boot.bin can't disassembly 1000013f which is branch instruction

Tags: mips, disassembly, u-boot

I tried disassembly u-boot.bin

> $ mips-unknown-linux-gnu-objdump -b binary -m mips:isa32
>   --adjust-vma=0x81000000 -D output/u-boot-2018.09/u-boot.bin

it out the raw instruction, can't recognize the branch code

```
81000000:   1000013f    0x3f010010
```

That is the first instruction is start.S

```
b reset
```

But if I disassembly start.o

> $ mips-unknown-linux-gnu-objdump -d --adjust-vma=0x81000000 -D
>   output/u-boot-2018.09/arch/mips/cpu/start.o

output:

```
81000000 <_start+0x0>:
81000000:       1000013f        b       81000500 <reset>
```

that disassembly correctly. why disassembly u-boot.bin can't recognize branch instruction.

Comment: add an option -EB to specify big endian format when disassembling, then works fine